# Neural network input with exponential decay

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Often, to improve learning rates, inputs to a neural network are preprocessed by scaling and shifting to be between -1 and 1. I'm wondering though if that's a good idea with an input whose graph would be exponentially decaying.  For instance, if I had an input with integer values 0 to 100 distributed with the majority of inputs being 0 and smaller values being more common than large values, with 99 being very rare.

Seems that scaling them and shifting wouldn't be ideal, since now the most common value would be -1.  How is this type of input best dealt with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you're using a sigmoid activation function which is symmetric around the origin:

[image]

The trick to speed up convergence is to have the mean of the normalized data set be 0 as well. The choice of activation function is important because you're *not only* learning weights from the input to the first hidden layer, i.e. normalizing the input *is not enough*: the input to the second hidden layer/output is learned as well and thus needs to obey the same rule to be consequential. In the case of non-input layers this is done by the activation function. The much cited [Efficient Backprop](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) paper by Lecun summarizes these rules and has some nice explanations as well which you should look up. Because there's other things like [weight and bias initialization](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html) that one should consider as well.

In chapter 4.3 he gives a formula to normalize the inputs in a way to have the mean close to 0 and the std deviation 1. If you need more sources, [this](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/section-16.html) is great faq as well.

I don't know your application scenario but if you're using symbolic data and 0-100 is ment to represent percentages, then you could also apply [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to the input layer to get better input representations. It's also worth noting that some people prefer scaling to [.1,.9] instead of [0,1]

Edit: Rewritten to match comments.

Comment: runDOSrun,  I'm not sure how your answer relates to my question.   I'm talking about the distribution of my input values and how to scale and shift them best so that learning is optimal.  I don't see how that relates to the various choices for activation function.

Comment: If you ask the question "why" normalize before "how", you'll see that it relates to the activation function. Look back to wherever you've read that the input gets normalized to -1 to 1 and you'll see the link. I'm not sure what else to say since my first sentence says how both concepts relate. You know what normalization is?

Comment: runDOSrun, Sorry, I'm still not seeing the relationship between your answer and my question.  I don't think the the goal of shifting and scaling the inputs as trying to fit the activation functions range, but instead as an attempt to make the error surface less of an ellipse and more of a circle. Geoff Hinton covers the idea in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN2DODxEcTg  Shifting inputs is covered at 1:28 and scaling at 5:29.

Comment: runDosRun, Are you suggesting that I preprocess my inputs by running them through a function such as tanh()?  I can think of many ways to normalize the inputs, and that's certainly one of them, but that's not my question. My question is more, given a set of positive integer data with a distribution that is heavily skewed to zero and the number of entries decays exponentially as the value increases, what is the best way to normalize the inputs?  How to best deal with this specific distribution of inputs?  Thanks for your help.